# Badge Suggestion: Modernizer

Tags: discussion, badges

Duplicate questions are discouraged, but an answer that was up-to-the minute last year may be fairly tired this year, so to encourage people to keep answers up-to-date, particularly the more highly voted questions and answers, perhaps a badge could be awarded for a / [so many]  revision[s] of at least [this length] on answers [at least so old] with at least [so many votes] that subsequently receive [so many more votes].

Comment: If they came through the suggested edit system, this might be cool. But you'd have a very narrow window in which you could earn it. Otherwise, people who can edit normally would (likely) 'improve' things that might not really need improving.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is needed. I don't think that editing someone *else's* answer and changing its substance (which seems like what you're suggesting) is really even *allowed*. I don't think we want to encourage this behavior.

I'd rather see someone post a *new* answer to the old question, but we already have `Necromancer` for that.

The only situation this doesn't cover is revising your own answer with updated information, but I don't know that a corner case like that is really worthy of a badge, especially since you're getting all of the rep for it anyway.